# My code does not run for large values of n

Tags: c, variables, integer, type-conversion

This code runs for values of n of the order of 100k but when it gets to a million it stops and crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    long int n, sum;
    n = 1000000;
    int f[];
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 2;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 2; f[i-1] < n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
        printf("%ld \n", f[i]);
        if(f[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + f[i]; 
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n", sum);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `int f[];` ? That shouldn't compile.

Comment: Invoke your compiler in standard mode. You will need to choose a size for `f` , e.g. `int f[5000];` and you should also add a check to your loop so that you exit gracefully when `i` reaches 5000. If you do not exit gracefully then you may get "stops and crashes" or other strange behaviour.

Comment: formatting!… aaargh…

Comment: Sorry! Its been years since I wrote any code in C/C++. Can you tell me what exactly the community looks for when you say that the code lacks formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot declare a very big local array because its sits in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

I'm sure your local variable `int f[];` is a typo (that won't compile). You probably meant (after having set `n`) something like `int f[n];` so you are using a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

The call stack has a limited size (typically a couple of megabytes on current desktops running Linux).

You should allocate your big array in the heap (so use a pointer):

```
 unsigned n = 1000000;
 int *f = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
 if (!f) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

then you'll better clear it (because heap `malloc`-allocated memory zones contain garbage values):

```
 memset(f, 0, n*sizeof(int));
```

then you can use it as you did.

At the end of your program (near end of `main` in your case) be sure to call `free(p);`; actually you should free a heap-allocated memory zone once you are sure to never use it. But beware (i.e. take care) of [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)!

Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Be scared of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if your system has it. Read also the wikipage on [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). When you'll be more fluent with C programming, you might be interested in sometimes using [Boehm conservative garbage collector for C](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Comment: The original code did not have `int f[1000000];` and did not intend to. `n` is not the array dimension.

Comment: f[] was a typo when I put it here....I understand now.Thank you! I havnt done much coding on C, though I have written a lot of MATLAB code. C is harder for someone who is used to the user friendliness of MATLAB I guess. Thanks for clearing that up for me.